# Como imprimir un array NxM cuando no es cuadrática

Tags: c++, array, dev-c++

Estoy en c++ y tengo una matriz NxM donde

```
n = 3;
m = 4;
```

entonces uso este código

```
    cout<<"\n\n VALORES DE A = \n\n";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nR ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j <nC; j++ ){  
            printf ("%11.1f",U[i][j]); 
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
```

Pero me queda de forma

```
1  2  3  4               1  2  3 
5  6  7  8   en vez de   4  5  6 
9 10 11 12               7  8  9
                        10 11 12
```

Y estoy buscando imprimirla de la segunda manera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo es cuestión de cambiar el orden de las variables de los for, primero se trabajará con el numero de columnas, y posteriormente con el numero de renglones, adjunto codigo.

```
   for (int i = 0 ; i < nC ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j <nR; j++ ){  
            printf ("%11.1f",U[i][j]); 
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
```

Comment: Lo hice pero poniendo los numeros del 1 al 9 se salto al 4 y al 8 y se trabo al final

Comment: ¿Tendrás el codigo completo? Me serviría mucho